# Search function works improperly

Tags: search, actions, pre-get-posts

So I am trying to edit my Search so it searches only for specific categories. I am adding this code to my `functions.php` file in child theme:

```
function searchcategory($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('cat','37');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchcategory');
```

So this is the issue: For example, when I run this code, my search does not even find anything.

Important notes:
1) First of all, I have created several taxonomies and custom post types with Toolset plugin, and these is ID of one of those taxonomies - I am looking up its ID by hovering cursor over the name of taxonomy. Could this be an issue?
2) When I run this code, which supposes to exclude all pages from search results, I still see some of the pages. It is weird.

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'page');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Does anyone know what may cause this issue?

Comment: What if you change `'37'` to `37`, an integer?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_Pages_from_Search_Results - what if you remove the line `return $query;` ? are you targeting a category or one of your taxonomies?

Comment: I am actually targeting one taxonomy, but I would go with category as well if it worked. So I need either taxonomy or category

Comment: Also, if I remove `return $query;`, it does not query anything. Just shows no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work OK, but... There are some problems with it. Let's break it apart and add some comments.

```
function searchcategory($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        // Checking only for is_search is very risky. It will be set to true
        // whenever param "s" is set. So your function will modify any wp_query with s,
        // for instance the one in wp-admin... But also any other, even if
        // the query isn't querying for posts...

        $query->set('cat','37');
        // You pass ID of term in here. It's a number. Passing it as string
        // is not a problem, but it's another bad practice, because it will
        // have to be converted to number.
    }
    return $query;

    // It's an action - you don't have to return anything in it. Your result 
    // will be ignored.
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchcategory');

// pre_get_posts is and action and not a filter.
// Due to the way actions/filters are implemented,
// you can assign your callback using `add_filter`,
// but it isn't a good practice.
```

So how to write it nicer?

```
function searchcategory($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', 37 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'searchcategory' );
```

Comment: thanks it worked as well. Now I am trying to make Search return different posts when I am on different pages. I am trying to use this code: 
`function search_classesx($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
     if is_page(54) { 
        $query->set( 'cat', 37 );
    }
    if is_page(1451) { 
        $query->set( 'cat', 40 );
    }

    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_classesx' );` But it does not work. Do you by any chance know why? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I added this same code:

```
function searchcategory($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('cat','37');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchcategory');
```

The problem was with Toolset plugin. For some reason, it was messing up the search results based on categories/taxonomies. Whatever it was, the code above works fine with original WordPress categories.

Comment: Read the answer from @Krzysiek. Many improvements can be made on those few lines.